# Minimum number of polynomials required to define given projective algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, projective-geometry

<sub>Note: This is a much simplified version of my [earlier question with the same title](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4608333/101420). I hope the simpler version has a better chance of generating answers, which I maybe then can use to find the answer to the original question myself. But answers there are of course still welcome too.</sub>

---

Let $V$ be a projective algebraic set, meaning that $V$ is the set of common zeroes of a finite set of homogeneous polynomials:

$$V = Z(f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n) \tag{1}\label{f}$$

Taking the geometric object $V$ at the left hand side of (\ref{f}) as fixed , I define $\mu$ to be the *smallest* possible value of $n$ that could be taken in (\ref{f}) for which we can still find $f_1, \ldots, f_\mu$ making the equation true.

> **Question:** Can $\mu$ be expressed in terms of *geometric* attributes of $V$, e.g. its number of irreducible components, their dimension and co-dimension, perhaps their degrees?

I admit that my notion of 'geometric' is a bit vague. I like to think about it as 'things we can just see when looking at $V$', but in reality I only can see these things if the ambient projective space has dimension as most 3 and the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$. For this question however I am interested in the case where the dimension of the space is $n$ and the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$. So the real meaning of 'geometric' then becomes 'things that a hypothetical $2n$-dimensional being can just see when looking at $V$', which is probably even more vague than 'geometric'.

> **Second question.** Let $\mathcal{I}(V)$ be (as always) the set of all homogeneous polynomials that vanish on $V$ and let $m$ be the (minimum) number of generators of $\mathcal{I}(V)$ as an ideal. How do $\mu$ and $m$ relate to each other?

I must say my intuition is torn here. On one hand it seems that $\mu$ and $m$ are the only two numbers of its kind (i.e. possible values of $n$ in (\ref{f})) that are uniquely defined in terms of $V$. This suggest they might be equal.

On the other hand $\mu$ is defined as the *smallest* of its kind, while $\mathcal{I}(V)$ is the *biggest* ideal that vanishes on $V$. So that would rather suggest that $m > \mu$ generically. But then perhaps their difference has a nice geometric interpretation?

Comment: You're saying projective algebraic 'set'. So you want the set-theoretic intersection?

Comment: As an example to elaborate, the twisted cubic in P^3 cannot be cut out scheme-theoretically by two homogenous polynomials, but can be cut out by set-theoretically. That is, there are f,g homogeneous such that V(f,g)_red = twisted cubic.

Comment: @CraniumClamp I thought I wanted the set-theoretic intersection because that one I understand. I know very little about schemes. But if the question has a in some sense 'better' or 'more natural' answer using scheme theoretic intersections I would be interested in learning about that too.

Comment: Your second comment goes directly against my intuition. I always thought schemes are the more general object, meaning that there are schemes that represent varieties plus a bunch of others. But that would imply you could only have *more* ways to cut out a given curve in the scheme theoretic setting than in the set-theoretic setting, not less Apparently this is not true, but how does this work. I guess we can take your $f$ and $g$ to be $x_1^2 - x_0x_2$ and $x_1^3 - x_0^2x^3$, following the definition of the twisted cubic curve in Hartshorne ex 1.2 But how do these $f, g$ not define schemes?

Comment: Yes, schemes are more general than varieties in many ways, one of which is exactly the issue here: to cut out something as a variety is to cut it out with no 'thickness'. If we look in the complex plane C^2 with two variables x,y, the equations y=0 and y^2=0 both cut out the x-axis as sets but clearly the second equation is a 'thicker' cutting, of second order. The first one is a variety, the second one is not.

Comment: In spirit of the above, there are two equations f = g = 0, f homogenous of degree 2 and g of degree 3 which cut out a 'thick' twisted cubic in P^3. So the answer to your question for V = twisted cubic is, mu = 2 while m = 3.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer to the second question! As for the first question: I get the impression that $m = 3$ for the twisted cubic itself, but $m = 2$ for the intersection of the twisted cubic with any affine chart, is that correct? This suggests to me (but I'd like to hear your opinion) that (while both are true) it would actually be easier to 'just see by looking at the curve' that $\mu = 2$ than that $m = 3$. This sort-of suggests to me that the first question is more likely to have an answer for $\mu$ than for $m$, but maybe I am getting it upsidedown again. What do you think?

Comment: @CraniumClamp I also have a further question. The number $\mu$ is the minimum cardinality of a set of hypersurfaces whose set theoretic intersection is $V$. Your comments suggest that instead I could or maybe should ask about the minimum cardinality of a set of hypersurfaces whose scheme theoretic intersection equals $V$. I didn't realize they could be different, but will look into that now. My question is: is this latter number always equal to the number $m$ for my post, or is that something that just happens to be the case for the twisted cubic but not in general?